# A blue-nosed automatic?

Tags: meaning

Take this passage from Agatha Christie's *The Seven Dials Mystery*. [Emphasis added]

> "Do you think you could go out and buy me a pistol, Stevens?"
>
> "A pistol, sir?"
>
> True to his training, Stevens betrayed no hint of surprise.
>
> "What kind of a pistol would you be requiring?"
>
> "The kind where you put your finger on the trigger and the thing goes on
>   shooting until you take it off again."
>
> "An automatic, sir."
>
> "That's it," said Jimmy. "An automatic. And I should like it to be a
>   **blue-nosed** one—if you and the shopman know what that is. In American
>   stories, the hero always takes his **blue-nosed automatic** from his hip
>   pocket."
>
> Stevens permitted himself a faint, discreet smile.
>
> "Most American gentlemen that I have known, sir, carry something very
>   different in their hip pockets," he observed. Jimmy Thesiger laughed.

In this passage, what is a "blue-nosed" gun?

In addition, in the 1930s, what would a fictional American gentleman be keeping in his hip pocket?

Comment: Given the publication date of *The Seven Dials Mystery* (1929) and the dates of Prohibition, it would be a [hip flask](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hip+flask&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) in the pocket.

Comment: As the answers suggest that there may not be any such thing as a "blue-nosed automatic" per se, it would be interesting to look for earlier citations of the phrase, to see if it really was common in American detective fiction.

Comment: I think it is possible Christie was conflating _snub-nose_ and _blue-steel_. The first is a revolver, and the second could be either a revolver or semi-auto. I recall another "famous" mystery writer who often spoke of her heroe's _Biretta_ with some authority...AFAIK there ain't no such make.

Comment: ...and what  a fashionable gent would carry in his hip pocket was possibly a flask of whiskey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a forum discussion on [suspect is armed with a blue nose revolver](http://www.thehighroad.org/archive/index.php/t-471379.html) that failed to come to any conclusion. But we here at ELU are made of sterner stuff...

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colt_Detective_Special) on the *Colt Detective Special* revolver says

> The Detective Special was initially available in both bright blued and nickel finishes...

I doubt Agatha Christie expected many of her readers to get that reference. She may simply have used it for artistic effect - "blued steel" implies heat-treating, which can either be taken to mean it's a higher-class weapon that's been more carefully manufactured, or maybe that it *has been used* (the blueing by implication arising from the heat of firing).

Comment: I came across that same article in my Google search before posting. I knew ELU would be able to sate my curiosity.

Comment: Gun bluing: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gun+bluing%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb

Comment: *Agatha Christie's* reference was to the phrase used by Raymond Chandler and many lesser American thriller writers: I am sure it was accurate as such . You may well be right about what the Americans meant, but neither Jimmy nor Christie seem very interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

With the very greatest respect to the author, she has confused a *self-loading pistol* with a fully automatic weapon, more commonly referred to as a machine-pistol. Thesiger has Stevens buy a "blue-nosed automatic", which is later described as a Colt, possibly a 1903 Colt Pocket Hammerless. This pistol had a blued finish, a heat and chemical treatment process which has long been a common method of resisting corrosion and imparting a pleasing appearance. Another "automatic" which appears in the story is a Mauser, possibly the 1914 model, also in a blued finish.

So to answer the original query — there's really no such thing as a "blue-nose gun", as any blued weapon will be treated on all its external surfaces — the whole thing will appear a dark blue.

Comment: The distinction between an *automatic* and a *revolver* was common well before the first machine pistols/ sub-machineguns.

Comment: I think she knew the difference. In the 1981 TV movie, at least, Thesiger says later that he pulled the trigger but the gun only fired once even tho he thought it would keep firing. The jokes is meant to be on him. He even refers to the trigger as "the button".

Comment: It should be obvious just from the extract that Jimmy Thesiger doesn't know anything about guns (other than what he's read in detective novels). What Christie knew is entirely separate to what her characters knew.

Answer (score 0):

The blue nosed automatic appears to be Colt .455 Auto, model 1911

Comment: Only on SE. The only correct answer is down voted.

Answer (score 0):

"The blue nosed automatic appears to be Colt .455 Auto, model 1911"
     i Agree, with exceptions.  The "blue-nosed" probably referenced a blued steel firearm, and Ms. Christie later says it is a Colt in .445, so it should be a Colt model 1911.  However the ".455" is an English rimmed round used in their Webley revolvers, and no Colt auto loader was chambered in that round (the bullet diameter of a .45 Auto is .451").  The Colt model 1911 was not full, only semi, auto, and Jimmy expresses his disappointment after he fires it and it only shoot once - he thinks he did something wrong!

Comment: http://files.webydo.com/150858/Colt%20455.PDF

Answer (score 0):

I found lots of references to “blue-nosed” guns as pistols, revolvers, & automatics on Newspapers.com, starting in the 1920s, as well as “blue, snub-nosed” guns. I'm sure it's a reference to a pistol that has been chemically blued & not a mistake or a specific make of pistol.

There are enough references to "blue-nose" firearms that it's clearly a term in common use from the 1920s to the 1960s but few enough (and lacking in firearm book references on Google Books) that it's likely not a technical or industry term and may even be a conflation of "blue steel" and "snub nose". (I found zero references to "blue-nose, snub-nose" firearms even tho I did find references to "blue, snub-nose" firearms.)

==Blue-nose==

"The blue nose of a revolver was jammed hard against his ribs." - Woodward News-Bulletin (Woodward, OK), 18 Aug 1922, p2.

"And then the thing that happened to Schucart also might happen to you--find yourself gazing in the barrel of a blue-nose revolver; or maybe the weapon would not have a blue nose, but that is immaterial." - Muncie Evening Press (Muncie, IN), 16 Apr 1935, p 4.

"A .38 calibre, blue-nose revolver was found by the two sleuths under a mattress in what they described as Massi's bedroom. It was a new weapon." - Morning Post (Camden, NJ), 6 Jan 1937, p 3.

"[W]hen asked what his business here had been by Captain John B Burbidge, he shrugged his shoulders and points at the small, blue-nose automatic pistol the officers had taken away from him." - Ogden Standard-Examiner (Ogden, UT), 29 Mar 1930, p 8.

"Of course, there are girls who are grafters and who hold up men for everything they can get out of them, just as truly as if they were pointing a blue-nose pistol at them instead of a pair of blue eyes." - St Louis Star and Times (St Louis, MO), 2 Jun 1936, p9.

"Police recovered a paper sack with about $46 in it, as well as cash from the suspect's pockets, an automatic blue nose pistol [sic]" - Arcadia Tribune (Arcadia, CA), 26 Oct 1972, p1.

==Blue, snub-nose==

"Detective Bud Farmer said the heavyset man entered the station carrying a blue snub-nose automatic." - Knoxville Journal (Knoxville, TN), 23 Dec 1963, p 3.

"One was about 5-11 and carried a blue snub nose pistol; the other was six feet and carried a chrome snub nose pistol." - Orlando Sentinel (Orlando, Florida), 9 Dec 1963.

Answer (score -1):

So I am thinking that the blue nose is from the heat effect of repeated use.  The metal of a heavily used weapon can take on a mottled blue color... especially at the muzzle.